# Need viber webservice or api address

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, api, viber

Is there any api or webservice to send message via viber through c# .net , and get delivery?
I googled and found an api for whats app but not for viber

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no Viber API available in C#.Net till now.

Comment: what about other languages and framworks?

Comment: We provide Viber API in a javascript sdk - https://github.com/amio-io/amio-sdk-js