# Mobile chat Apps .net Api to send message

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

As far as I know Whats App blocked the whats app .net API.

So the question: Is there any other mobile chatting App that provide 
.net API for sending messages
i.e (line , viper , etc)?

Comment: did u try Signalr .net ?

Comment: Signalr is to Create a chat i need to send messages to clients using any existing chat App (Whatsapp - line - viper etc)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Facebook Messenger
try [facebook-messenger-net-lib](https://github.com/HiznyakNikita/facebook-messenger-net-lib/tree/develop/FacebookMessengerLib) it is a C# library to talk to facebook messenger API [nuget link](https://www.nuget.org/packages/facebook-messenger-net-lib/) 

For Line 
you can see this link [LineBot-Sample-for-DotNet](https://github.com/kiyoaki/LineBot-Sample-for-DotNet)

For Viber 
Couldn't found one for .NET or any other platform see this questions
[send message by viber or whatsapp programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20946461/send-message-by-viber-or-whatsapp-programmatically) 
[Need viber webservice or api address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28611238/need-viber-webservice-or-api-address)

For Skype 
[Skype API](https://docs.botframework.com/en-us/skype/getting-started/#navtitle) 
[Microsoft Bot Builder C# SDK](https://docs.botframework.com/en-us/csharp/builder/sdkreference/)

Comment: Thank you but i am looking for some thing related to mobile number Facebook is mainly about email not mobile (not all users add mobile number to facebook)

Comment: Line Will work but What about viber  What other chat programs have a .net Api

Comment: I have been edit the answer and add Skype and Viber descriptions , this should be answer your question , please accept